# The goal "copy-dependencies" does not copy the parent pom

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin, parent-pom

My project structure is like this:

```
* Foo
  - API
  - Core
  - OSGi
```

All child projects define *Foo* as their parent (parent has dependencyManagement).

Another team is going to use my project. They only need my API layer and they cannot access my maven repository.

I need to give them all the dependencies of my API so I executed the following maven command:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=compile -Dmdep.copyPom
-Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout
```

The dependency-plugin copies everything just fine except for the parent pom. How can I add the parent pom.xml to the output folder?

Answer (score 1):

see the addParentPoms option here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html