# Obtaining all parent poms in a repository

Tags: maven, repository, parent-pom

I have a huge local repository, which also contains unneeded jars (they are needed for other projects, but not for the task at hand). I've extracted the dependencies of my project using the `maven dependency plugin` and parsed that information into `deploy` commands in order to deploy those jars to another, remote repository. I couldn't have copied directly, because of access restrictions.

However, now compilation fails and I discovered that many of the issues I've already solved were due to the fact that the parent poms for some of the jars I was using were missing.

Is there a way to programmatically obtain all the parent poms of the dependencies of a certain project, similar to finding the dependencies themselves?

I would try parsing the directory tree directly and deploying every pom which doesn't have a jar counterpart, but I really hope there are better alternatives.

Comment: Take a look at the copy-dependencies goal with the addParentPom option described at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems like it might do the trick :)

Comment: I got it from another question with the parent-pom tag, but can't work out how to add the link using the mobile Stack Exchange app.

Comment: Here is the related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21375200/274350